# Unable to import a JSP project into Eclipse as a dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to import into Eclipse a web project that uses Spring, Hibernate, and JSPs.  This web application was developed also in Eclipse, and for some reason, when I try to import into my workspace, I am able to import it as a standard project, which prevents me from running it on Tomcat.

I need to import this project into Eclipse as a dynamic web project so that it runs on Tomcat that is setup in Eclipse.  I know Tomcat is running fine because I am able to deploy a very basic "hello world" dynamic web app within Eclipse.  I am using the latest version of Eclipse Java EE IDE for web developers Helios SR1, and Tomcat v6.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change project facets

go to project `properties -> Project Facets -> and checked 'Dynamic web module' checkbox.`

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt solution, it worked!  Take care.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways in eclipse

Firstly open eclipse and do the following

```
File->Dynamic Web Project->NewWebProject
```

copy the contents of the pervious project into the NewWebProject folder then right click on New Web Project

```
Properties->Project Facets
```

and check if **dynamic web module** is checked